# Reading numbers from file to multidimensional arrays

Tags: python-2.7, multidimensional-array, text-files

I have integer numbers in a text file to be assigned to an array C[5][100].
My data is in this format:

```
17 40 35 24 50 15 31 38 48 18 16 44 
41 10 26 50 48 20 24 12 48 24 34 39 
...............
```

I am trying the code below but the error I get is this:

> ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 1005 to array axis with dimension 100

```
text_file = open("c051001.txt", "r")

C=np.zeros((5,100))

for i in range(agent):
    C[i,]=map(int, (value for value in text_file.read().split()))
```

Number of integers in the file is more than 500 but I want to assign the remainder of numbers to another array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to divide the data into appropriate chunks.  A simple way to do this could be:

```
agent = 5
resource = 1
sz = 100

C = np.zeros((agent, sz))

idx = 0
chunk = sz
for i in range(agent):
    C[i, ] = list(map(int, data[idx:idx + chunk]))
    idx += chunk

# Assign the following 500 integers into another array of A[5,100,1]
A = np.zeros((agent, sz, resource))

for k in range(resource):
    for i in range(agent):
        A[i, :, k] = list(map(int, data[idx:idx + chunk]))
        idx += chunk

trailing_data = data[idx:]
```

Comment: Works perfect thank you FredrikHedman! I tried to use the same block to assign the following 500 integers into another array of A[5,100,1] but I could not find the right syntax. This is what I thought that would work but it is not:

     chunk = 100
     for k in range(resource):
         for i in range(agent):
             a[i, ,k] = list(map(int, data[idx:idx + chunk]))
             idx += chunk

     trailing_data = data[idx:]

Comment: I updated the suggested solution.  Still, seems like a good idea to have a good look at https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#indexing-slicing-and-iterating

Comment: Also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers